# Adding Native Headers to Stomp Client

Tags: android, websocket, client, stomp, java-websocket

I have been working on implementing Stomp Client on Android, I am using [this](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid) library. I have successfully connected and I can receive message from the server, but now I am required to add native headers to the connection. So I edited my code to follow this pattern:

```
StompClient mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, TerminalDetails.WEB_SOCKET_URL, map);
```

Where "map" is an HashMap defined as below:

```
map.put("clientChannelId", TerminalDetails.staffId);
    map.put("clientUsername", TerminalDetails.userName);
```

But the header does not get to the server on connection. The back end developer says header is missing in the connection.

Has anybody faced this error before or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read through the implementation of the Stomp library and i see that i was using the wrong header the header in the Stomp.over() static method is http header so I later passed List of StompHeader into the stompClient.connect() method.

So, stompClient.connect(List);

for more information, Check out the source [here](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/ua/naiksoftware/stomp/client/StompClient.java)

Answer (score 0):

Another way in Kotlin is

```
val headerMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
        Pair("Header1", "Value1"),
        Pair("Header2", "Value2")
    )
mStompClient = Stomp
     .over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, SOCKET_URL, headerMap)
     .withServerHeartbeat(30000)
```